# Laravel join with "and" and "or" in the where clause

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How can I write a Laravel 5 Eloquent query like this SQL?

```sql
where ( (table1.fname like %xxxxx% )
    OR (table1.lname like %xxxxx%) )
    AND table1.is_active != 0
```

I have already tried

```
->where('users.is_active', '!=', 2)
    ->where('users.name', 'like' , '%'. $search .'%')
    ->orWhere('users.lname', 'like' , '%'. $search .'%')
    ->orWhere('users.email', 'like' , '%'. $search .'%') ->get();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the **Advanced join Clauses** in [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#)

```
DB::table('users')
    ->join('contacts', function ($join) {
        $join->on('users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
             ->where('contacts.user_id', '>', 5);
    })
    ->get();
```

joins

**EDIT**

I think i misunderstood the question. To do nested wheres you can do the following thing:

```
\DB::table('table1')->...->where(function($query) {
    $query->where('table1.fname', 'like', '%xxxxx$')->orWhere('table1.lname', 'like', '%xxxx%);
})->where('table1.is_active', '!=', 0);
```

Comment: here is my query :   $members = DB::table('users')
          ->select('users.id','users.name','users.lname','users.email','users.phone','users.address_1','users.address_2','users.city','users.postcode','users.unit','users.photo','users.created_at','countries.name as country')
          ->join('countries','users.country','=','countries.id')
          ->where('users.is_active', '!=', 2)
          ->where('users.name', 'like' , '%'. $search .'%')
          ->orWhere('users.lname', 'like' , '%'. $search .'%')
          ->orWhere('users.email', 'like' , '%'. $search .'%')
          ->get();

Comment: i don't want the users who has is_active = 2

Comment: Ok i think i misunderstood the question. I have the solution, give me a sec

Comment: i want : where ( (table1.fname like %xxxxx% ) OR (table1.lname like %xxxxx%) ) AND (table1.is_active != 0)

Comment: please check look at this, i post it more clear https://laravel.io/forum/laravel-join-query-where-and-or-both-cluse

Comment: Just try with a dummy value first to check if the query works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Model** for this:

```
TableModel::where('fname', 'like', '%xxxxx%')
             ->orWhere('lname', 'like', '%xxxxx%')
             ->where('is_active', '!=', 0)
             ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data =  DB::table('table1')->where('fname', 'like', '%xxxxx%')
         ->orWhere('lname', 'like', '%xxxxx%')
         ->where('is_active', '!=', 0)
         ->get();
//add use DB; in your controller
```

Comment: here is my query :   $members = DB::table('users')      ->select('users.id','users.name','users.lname','users.email','users.phone','users.address_1','users.address_2','users.city','users.postcode','users.unit','users.photo','users.created_at','countries.name as country')
          ->join('countries','users.country','=','countries.id')
          ->where('users.is_active', '!=', 2)
          ->where('users.name', 'like' , '%'. $search .'%')
          ->orWhere('users.lname', 'like' , '%'. $search .'%')
          ->orWhere('users.email', 'like' , '%'. $search .'%')
          ->get();

Comment: i dont want the user who's is_active = 2

Comment: i want : where ( (table1.fname like %xxxxx% ) OR (table1.lname like %xxxxx%) ) AND (table1.is_active != 0)

Comment: yes as i defiend it in DB::table('table1'), this is your table name  table and after that where query.

Comment: here is more clear, please check once https://laravel.io/forum/laravel-join-query-where-and-or-both-cluse

Comment: @saiful just add in the last your query before the get where('is_active',!=2)->get();

Answer (score 0):

To have grouped sub-clauses that should evaluate as a whole, you can pass `where()` a closure. Then you want a second `where` call for the check on the `is_active` column:

```php
$value = '%xxxxx%';

$collection = Model::where(function ($models) use ($value) {
    $models->where('fname', 'like', $value)
           ->orWhere('lname', 'like', $value);
})
    ->where('is_active', '!=', 0)
    ->get();
```